# Fallout 1 and 2 version on GOG and Steam

Tags: steam, fallout, fallout-2, gog

Is the version on sale on both of these online digital distribution is the uncensored or not?

Comment: There's a censored version?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yes. Both games have version where the children on the games are removed to prevent them from being killed by the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According from what I read the US version is uncensored while the EURO version is censored. So it would **depend what region you are buying the game from.**

The worst thing about the censored version all they really did was change the sprites for kids to be invisible, the kids are still in your game but invisible! This was apparently done because European games at the time due to legal restrictions could not contain children in them. The good thing you can just change the sprites to the US version and they appear just fine.

According to this [post](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=59651) from the No Mutants Allowed forum it does look like it is the censored version. This GOG.com store [page](http://www.gog.com/forum/fallout_series/is_this_euro_censored_or_us_uncensored) mentions this as well. This [page](http://vault42.org/fallout-1-2-enhancement-guide/) I found mentions it as the censored version as well. So it would appear if you are outside the US and buy it on GOG you get the UK Censored Version. You can however download the fix [here](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/dload.php?action=file&file_id=78) as the post talks about it and the game will work fine.

Just for people looking for the files to uncensor both versions. Here are the files for [Fallout 1](http://www.moddb.com/games/fallout/downloads/fallout-1-child-patch) and [Fallout 2](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/dload.php?action=file&file_id=78).

Answer (score 2):

The GOG version is definitely uncensored.

On Steam it depends on where you live.

However if something is cencored Steam will notice you about that.

You can see it in the following screenshot (german store, the orange box right under the video says "reduced violence")

[image]

Maybe i should advice you to the [No Mutants Allowed Forum](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40590) - *unofficial* expansion of Fallout 2 (Uncut Patch included)

Here a [Link](http://fallout-files.de/index.php?c=details&f_id=8) to an Uncut Patch for Fallout 1 (German Fallout-Files Page)